# How to center image in column Datables BootStrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

With Datables BootStrap, to cnter img in column I do this

```
$('#despatchEntryDetails').dataTable({
        "responsive": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Numéro" },
            { "title": "Date création" },
            { "title": "Sujet" },
            { "title": "Etat" },
            { "title": " ",  
              "width": "32px", 
              "orderable": false, 
              "data": null,
              "className": "dt-body-center",
              "defaultContent": '<input name="submit" id="viewDetail" type="image" src="btn_vuedetail.gif" onclick="viewDetail();" />',
            }       
        ],
        data: dataSet
    });
  });
```

Expected this to center image in the last column but it don't seem to be working.

Ref: [DataTables Cell classes options](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes#Cell-classes)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your code works fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/bk7jr1mh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gyrocode.com Thank you for your help.

I found why it did not work on my site. I forgot to add the stylesheet: `jquery.dataTables.css`

With this stylesheets, It's OK

```
<!-- DataTables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```